# How come DVI KVM's are 10x more expensive than VGA KVMs?

Tags: vga, dvi, kvm-switch

KVM switches for VGA displays vs for DVI displays: From examining prices both these days and a couple of times over the past year or two, I've noticed that, generally, 2-machine KVM switches, with USB ports for keyboard and mouse, are about an order-of-magnitude, 10x or so, more expensive for DVI displays.

DVI is newer and more complex technology, so maybe the hardware for it is a bit more expensive, but were talking about a passive component which doesn't do any DAC, just switches wires. So where does the 10x price difference come from?

I realize that DVI-based KVMs are newer on the market. However, DVI has been around for more than a decade already; and while VGA KVMs have been around for longer, they used to have PS/2 connectors rather than USB ones. So the age difference doesn't explain such a price gap. Also, I'm not comparing apples and oranges w.r.t. audio connector switching, or massive metal vs lightweight plastic boxes.

Comment: einpoklum, I asked about this on Meta.  See https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13220/when-is-cost-an-on-topic-question.

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption that the KVM is a passive component is wrong. Even with VGA, the KVM has to correctly manage access to the [EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data) in the monitor. The video sources cannot read the monitor EDID simultaneously. However the video signals are totally analog so once the sources know what format to send, they can be switched in and out as needed.

DVI (the digital part) is not just unidirectional signals, there is a whole protocol that requires timing synchronisation on both sides of a link. On top of that is [HDCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection) where encryption keys need to be synchronised.

There might be some clever trickery to reset the links every time the video source is switched, but I think the normal way to do this is to decode the video data in the KVM, then re-encode for the monitor. This means the links to the monitor and video sources needn't be reset all the time. However, to do this you need a rather powerful FPGA (or bespoke ASIC) to at least maintain multiple input links and to forward the right video data to the output links.

In addition to all that, I'm sure there's a lot of testing to iron out quirks in different devices. These are probably widely known for VGA, but not so much for DVI.

Comment: If a homunculus pulled the video cable out of my video card causing my multi-monitor setup to be upset, I'd pull the homunculus out of the KVM switch and stab it repeatedly.

Comment: don't forget that DVI KVMs need to support both VGA(DVI-A) and HDMI(DVI-D), for this reason HDMI KVMs are less expensive than DVI

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Video cards have no problem with you pulling cables out of them. They're designed to support this.

Comment: @Jasen: That point could be developed into an answer.

Comment: @einpoklum: I'm going to guess that you've never actually had a multi-monitor setup then.

Comment: @einpoklum: While PCs are typically pretty good about hot plug detection, there are other devices that can output DVI and the quality of their implementations can vary wildly. In any case, with a KVM you want the input to think it still has a monitor attached even when it isn't actually connected. With PCs, the layout of windows may not be preserved after disconnecting and reconnecting a monitor. Some applications may run into trouble if there is no monitor for their output to appear on. I think there are so many problems that a 'homunculus' KVM would be far more annoying than it'd be worth.

Comment: While the gist of this answer is correct (i.e. the KVM is not a passive device), the repeated use of *"input"* is ambiguous, and therefore confusing if not wrong.  The KVM switches both input and output signals.  Yet there are ambiguous statements like *"The inputs cannot read the EDID..."*, and even worse *"the inputs know what to send..."*.  *"Inputs"* are for receiving not sending.

Comment: To be clear, a KVM switches one keyboard, a video monitor and a mouse among several PCs.  @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams your mention of *"multi-monitor setup"* seems irrelevant.

Comment: @sawdust: The desk I am sitting at right now has two monitors and two computers. One monitor is exclusively connected to my workstation via HDMI, and the other is connected to my workstation via DVI and the other computer via VGA. If I were to use a DVI KVM switch for the second monitor then my workstation would detect any disconnection and switch my desktop to a single monitor. And don't get me started about when I tried using a HDMI switch on my *primary* monitor; *that* was an exercise in pain...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: To be honest, I doubt the reason for these prices is vendors' care for supporting multi-monitor setups, crossing the t's and dotting the i's. Perhaps that's true for certain premium KVMs, but not generally. IMO.

Comment: A KVM cannot be a passive device since it can respond to a hot-key sequence to perform the switch function, i.e. it's recognizing the electronic  scancodes transmitted by the keyboard.  But apparently a [DisplayPort switch](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00ZK2S71W/?tag=stackoverflow17-20)  can be a passive device according to its seller!  Strangely for a *"simple mechanical switch"* the seller also warns that it cannot be used in reverse! VGA switches can be used in either direction.

Comment: @sawdust : not so confusing. The KVM may well have some ports marked as "input" (e.g., data coming from a computer) & different ports marked as "output" (e.g., data going to a monitor), for the sake of user-friendliness, even though you're technically correct that one of the devices plugged into an "input" port may actually be performing "output" during bi-directional communication that a protocol requires.  As another example, although a monitor can send info to a PC (so the PC can determine whether something is plugged in), monitors are still typically classified as output devices (not I/O)

Comment: @TOOGAM --  My comment pertains to the original post.  Try reading the original post before you comment.  The fact that the post was edited confirms that my point was valid.

Comment: @sawdust You mentioned the answer being "confusing".  If confusion has been reduced, I'm happy for that, but even after investigating the earlier post, I don't retract my earlier statement.  That is because the updates to the post do not change the reality that an "output" device can technically send information back, and thereby technically provide "input", even though people still classify it as an "output device" rather than an "I/O device" (which mainly provides input and output).

Comment: I remember some people recommended using a particular KVM to strip a HDCP and to be able to see the full HD content on a non-HDCP compliant display. These things really can do a lot other than mechanical switches.

Comment: @TOOGAM -- Your confusion is that you think your comment is related to mine.  It is not.  I pointed out bad semantics by the OP.  You want to point out bi-directional I/O. They are not connected, other than there's the occurrence of the word *"input"*.